# How to create pagination with category from database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Hi all I am a new codeigniter I have problame with pagination in codeigiter I try to search on google youtube codeigniter document and other site and I folowwing but I can not 
**The problame in my code is with my $limit I limt 1 it shows 3 burger
and When I click Link pagination eror said 404 Page Not Found**
 who can help me please:
My database table:

```
product:
id title image category
1  a     a.jpg burger
2  b     b.jpg burger
3  c     c.jpg burger
4  d     d.jpg piza
5  e     e.jpg piza
6  f     f.jpg piza
```

I want the result pagination with category burger by burger, pagination pizza by pizza

My model code:

```
<?php
class Product_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_product($category="") {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    function get_total($category="") {
        $this->db->select('count(*) AS num_row');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row()->num_row;
    }
}
```

controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('product_model','product');
    }
 public function menu()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['sides'] = $this->product->get_product('sides');
        $total_sides = $this->product->get_total('sides');
        $limit_sides = 1;
        $link_sides = 'http://localhost/mbl/burger';
        $data['pagination_sides'] = $this->pagination($total_sides,$limit_sides,$link_sides);

        $data['beverages'] = $this->product->get_product('beverages');
        $total_beverages = $this->product->get_total('beverages');
        $limit_beverages = 1;
         $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $link_beverages = 'http://localhost/mbl/beverages';
        $data['pagination_beverages'] = $this->pagination($total_beverages,$limit_beverages,$link_beverages);


        $data['burger'] = $this->product->get_product('burger');
        $total_burger = $this->product->get_total('burger');
        $limit_burger = 1;
        $link_burger = 'http://localhost/mbl/site/menu/burger';
        $data['pagination_burger'] = $this->pagination($total_burger,$limit_burger,$link_burger);

        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('nav_view');
        $this->load->view('content_view');
        $this->load->view('content_left_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('content_right_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }
    private function pagination($total ,$per_page ,$link) {
        $config['base_url'] = $link;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        return $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
```

my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Pizza</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($pizza as $val) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $val->title; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<?php echo $pagination_pizza; ?>

<hr>

<h1>Burger</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($burger as $val) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $val->title; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<?php echo $pagination_burger; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Who can help me please or edit my code and have a new code for me :( :(

Comment: What exactly, is not working as expected??

Comment: wrong link and lots .help me please I am very need help

Comment: You should add what kind of wrong links do you get and what other problems do you have? Don't expect from anyone to just guess your problem. Or if he does it may not be your actual problem.

Comment: ok I will edit more . but  could u help me please I am very need help

Answer (score 0):

In your controller replace code inside function

```
 $data = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url('My_controller/paginationExample');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->product->count_all('sides');
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["allData"] = $this->My_model->paginationExample($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["pagination_beverages"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

   $config["base_url"] = base_url('controller/function');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->product->count_all(burger);
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["allData"] = $this->My_model->paginationExample($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["pagination_burger"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

for more read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-do-pagination-in-codeigniter/

Comment: OK VERY THZ i WILL TST UR CODE NOW

Answer (score 0):

In your controller-

```
 $this->load->library("pagination");
         $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url().'Controller/function/'.$id;
        $config['total_rows']=$this->your_model->get_records_count($id);
        $config['per_page']=5;
        //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4; // if passing values else replace 4 with 3

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        $this->data['record'] = $this->your_model->get_records($id,$config['per_page'],$page);
        $this->$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('your view page', $this->data);
```

In model-

```
function name($id,$limit, $start){

        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $records=$this->db->get('table', $limit, $start)->result();
        return $records;
}
```

In your view- 
Either you call- `$this->pagination->create_links();`
Or `echo "$links";`

Refer-
[How to create Pagination in Codeiginter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101513/how-to-create-pagination-in-codeiginter)

[how to create pagination for url with parameters in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780440/how-to-create-pagination-for-url-with-parameters-in-codeigniter)

Comment: what is record count ?

Comment: if you have any data to pass mention that name,record count is the function name specified in my model,you can specify your function name and ,member_model is my model name.

Comment: I try to fowing ur code but have error undefine $id. help me please I very need help from u ?

Comment: in the model has only one function name

Comment: what is  get_records_count?

Comment: get_records_count is the function i have used to retrieve the count of the record to be displayed. get_record is the function that retrieve all the records,$id is the value i pass in the url,if you don't have any values to pass remove it.Note:- if you don't have any values to pass make your `uri_segment` to 3.

Comment: Hi brother I am very sorry I can not do it caz I am a new of codeigniter. I just want the result get data category pagination burger by burger pizza by pizza. could u have the easy code for me ?

Comment: I have mentioned two links on the answer,refer those to get an idea.